# Does Application Insights Live Stream get confused when apps is deployed across multiple Environments each with its own version of the AI?

Tags: asp.net, azure-application-insights

I have a basic old ASP.NET application with various versions of the application deployed to multiple environments dev, test, staging etc.

As time goes on the AI packages are updated so eventually the versions progress through the environments.  So even in test, there may be multiple instances of the same application are deployed to the test servers each with a potentially different version of AI.

Most have now been upgraded to at least 2.2.0 and some of the latest are using 2.4.1 of AI.

But does this cause the Live Stream to fail reporting server side telemetry?

Up until and including version 2.2.0 being the latest across environments, Live Stream was working as expected, but as I've started deploying updates to 2.4.0+, the server side telemetry is now no longer logged - even for test instances still on the older AI packages.

The client side telemetry continues to be logged as expected.

Is there something I need to be aware of when upgrading AI?

NOTE: The distinction between server side and client side telemetry is based just on the difference between the JavaScript based events fired by AI in the browser versus the .NET based telemetry fired from the server.

Also, to clarify the client side telemetry was being captured but not any server telemetry. And neither was being seen in the Live Stream, only (eventually) in the standard logs.

Comment: Can you please clarify the following:
- do you see any impact on regular non-live telemetry?
- what do you mean by "server side" and "client side" telemetry? How do you draw the distinction?

Comment: telemetry isn't being logged at all?  or just live stream isn't working with 2.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least for the server telemetry and the live stream updating it seems that perhaps a change in the applicationinsights.config file may have been my downfall.

I basically just had a stock standard copy of the config that was originally created a long time ago.

Subsequent updates of AI have always left it untouched or I generally saw notes to create a copy for save keeping and if need to restore any custom configuration. Since I never customised the config, I never bothered trying to update it post AI updates.

I ended up trying to use what looked like a newer version of the config from a clean web project and latest install of AI and suddenly everything was working again.

I am not sure if I just missed some notification that there was a major change or perhaps at some point my config got corrupted but it seems all fixed again now.